# Always block with posedge triggering somehow works at time 0

Tags: verilog

I wrote a basic piece of Verilog code.

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
module lab3_2(
            input[3:0] command,
            input CLK,
            input mode,
            output reg [7:0] total_time1,
            output reg [7:0] total_time0
     );
     initial begin
     total_time1 = 8'b00000000;
     total_time0 = 8'b00000000;

     end

     always @(posedge CLK) begin

            if(total_time1 == 8'b00000001 && total_time0 == 8'b00001001)
                begin
                total_time0 <= 8'b00000000;
                total_time1 <= 8'b00000000;
                end
            else if(total_time0 == 8'b00001001)
                begin
                total_time1 <= 8'b00000001;
                total_time0 <= 8'b00000000;
                end
            else
                begin
                total_time0 <= total_time0 + 8'b00000001;
                end
        end

endmodule
```

It counts time up to 20, `total_time1` showing the leftmost digit  and `total_time0` showing the rightmost digit.
If `total_time1` = 1 and `total_time0` = 5, then it is the 15th time that the `always` block worked.

My problem is that when I try  this testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns /1ps

module lab3_2_testbench;

reg[3:0] command;
reg CLK;
reg mode ;
wire[7:0] total_time1;
wire[7:0] total_time0;


lab3_2 uut(
.command(command),
.CLK(CLK),
.mode(mode),
.total_time1(total_time1),
.total_time0(total_time0)
);


initial CLK = 1;
    always #5 CLK = ~CLK;

initial begin
$monitor("Time=%t | command=%b mode=%b| total_time1=%b total_time0=%b   CLK=%b      ", $time, command, mode,total_time1,total_time0,CLK);
mode = 0 ;


command = 4'b0000;

$display("Current simulation time = %t",$time);
    #10;
    $display("Current simulation time = %t",$time);

    $finish;





end

endmodule
```

What I get as output is:

```
Time=                   0 | command=0000 mode=0| total_time1=00000000 total_time0=00000001   CLK=1      
Time=                5000 | command=0000 mode=0| total_time1=00000000 total_time0=00000001   CLK=0      
Current simulation time =                10000
Stopped at time : 10 ns : File "/home/bs04/e2237006/Desktop/liy/testbench_part2.v" Line 35 **
```

How come `total_time0` is equal to 1 at time time 0?  Should it be not 0? I thought that the only way to increase `total_time0` is via triggering the `always` block, but how did I manage to trigger the `always` block at time 0?

According to my code, `CLK` starts as 1.

Comment: I think CLK going from x to 1 might be triggering the posedge. `initial CLK = 0`  should stop this.

Comment: @david Shah , yes it does . If I change  clk= 1 to clk = 0  . It does not trigger ,so is it safe to say that my module is  designed as expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the testbench, `CLK` is declared as a `reg`, and the initial value of a `reg` is `x`.  Then you assign it to 1.  Since the `x` to 1 transition is a posedge, the always block is triggered, and the `else` clause is executed, incrementing `total_time0`.